# Which Hessian to use to compute standard errors

Tags: r, maximum-likelihood, econometrics, standard-error, hessian

Let that I have a data vector $\textbf{x} = (x_1,x_2,x_3....x_n)$

Say these are realizations of IID  random variables having a common density $f_\theta$

Likelihood computed using $i^\text{th}$ observation is $l_i(\theta) = log (f_\theta(x_i))$

Total likelihood is  $L(\theta) = \sum_{i=1}^n log (f_\theta(x_i))$

Say, I have no other way but use numerical optimization to maximize total likelihood and arrived at estimate $\hat{\theta}$.

At this  $\hat{\theta}$ I can compute hessian using each observation and also hessian using total likelihood function.

Say hessian computed using $L(\theta)$ is $H_L$

Similarly, sum of hessians computed from individual observations is $ H_I = \sum_{i=1}^n H_i$ where $H_i$ is hessian computed from observation $i$.

Given that these hessians are computed numerically and that sample is not very large, $H_L$ and $H_I$ would be at least a little different. My question is which one is superior in computing standard errors of the parameter estimates. I am choosing between using ${-H_L}^{-1}$ or ${-H_I}^{-1}$ to compute covariance matrix of parameter estimates.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2335893?uid=3738744&uid=2&uid=4&sid=21106197081021

Comment: Thanks for the paper. It is quite dense to figure out the answer to my question. If you have an idea about which Hessian is better, could you please comment on it. Thanks.